# ssh2_exec don`t working properly with dynamic variable

Tags: php, ssh

I`m having stunning problem with ssh2_exec:

This code working good:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "smtp-cli --verbose --host=server.com --enable-auth --user=login --pass=password");
```

This code working bad:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "smtp-cli --verbose --host=".$server." --enable-auth --user=".$login." --pass=".$password);
```

Where i was wrong? :(

It was need to trim variables, sorry for this question :)